# The definite article before superlative degree

Tags: articles, adjectives, definite-article, superlatives

What are the special cases when we can't use "the" before superlative degree?
I'd like the answers with proper explanations.
Some of the examples:

1. He is most likely to succeed.
2. It is fairest of all methods.
3. I have read many books. "Against all odds" is best of all.

Comment: What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: When a superlative is in the predicative position, we drop the article, e.g.: _"Gin is best with a splash of tonic."_ Do you understand what is meant by _predicate_?

Answer (score -1):

The definite article "the" is not used before the superlative mainly in three cases:

1. When "most" means "extremely". For example, your sentence (1), which is by the way the only one that is correct in your set, means: He is extremely/highly likely to succeed.
2. When the superlative is not accompanied by a noun, either implicit or explicit. In P.E.Dant's example above:

   - Gin is **best** with a splash of tonic,

there is no noun, either tacit or express, after "best". Actually, "best" there means "ideal" and refers to "gin" itself. However, if somebody asks:

A. What's your favourite drink?
B could answer: In my opinion, gin is **the best** (drink).

When you use a phrase that indicates the group within which or the place where a certain item shows some feature in its superlative degree (by comparison with all the other items in the group), then you **have to** use "the" -- that's why your examples (2) and (3) are wrong:

2'. It is **the** fairest **of** all methods.

3'. I have read many books. "Against all odds" is **the** best **of** all (the books I've read).

Here's an example with a locative phrase:

- Susan is **the** best student **in** my class.

3. In some verbal phrases with verbs of liking, "the" is optional:

- Which book do you like (the) most/best?

According to [this page](https://jakubmarian.com/like-more-vs-like-better-like-the-most-vs-like-most-like-the-best-vs-like-best/), the options with "the" are considered by some to be less grammatical.

In support and as a supplement of what I said under (1) and (2) above (as well as of what @BenKovitz says here: You can even put **a** in front of a superlative when you intend the superlative to designate only a very high degree of something rather than the one item with the highest degree: *The hermitage is a most curious piece of architecture.*), we find all of this clearly explained by Quirk below:

[image: Superlative in attributive position]

[image: Superlative in predicative position]

The superlative without the definite article may function as a relative superlative (compared with other members of the group) or as an absolute superlative or intensifier (without entailing such comparison).

Comment: In such examples as the one in my comment, the important thing is that the superlative is in the _predicative_ position: we can say _"Gin is best"_, but we cannot say _"Best is gin with a splash of tonic"_ even though no noun accompanies the superlative.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Being in predicative position does not necessarily entail dropping the article. See my example: *In my opinion, gin is **the** best.* Also, "predicative" is not the opposite of "subject", but the opposite of "attributive": gin is best vs. the best drink.

Comment: Certainly we do not always, nor must we, omit the article when the superlative in the predicative position, but when we do, it is there and not in the subject. I noticed that you don't mention this in your answer, and it's an important point.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Sorry I have to disagree. You forget to mention the use of the indefinite article in attributive and even in subject position: *A most interesting book has just been published.* What makes the definite article unnecessary and wrong in that position is the absence of the noun.

Comment: In _A most interesting book has just been published_, the subject is _book_, and _most_ modifies _interesting_. There may well be one, but I can't think of an instance in which a naked superlative serves as the subject.

Comment: *A most interesting book* is not a superlative.  In that phrase, *most* is an intensifier and means 'very'.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I obviously meant to say that a superlative adjective without "the" could very well be within the subject, not be the subject.

Comment: @snailplane I explained that in my point (1).

Comment: It seems to me you forget what the OP asked. My answer is in reply to his question.

Comment: As I think @snailplane is trying to point out, your answer says: _"The definite article 'the' is not used before the superlative mainly in three cases: 1. When "most" means 'extremely'."_ — but when "most" means "extremely", it is not a superlative!

Comment: And predicative is not the same as predicate!

Comment: @P.E.Dant Please be consistent. You should then downvote the question you just submitted as a possible duplicate where it says: You can even put 'a' in front of a superlative when you intend the superlative to designate only a very high degree of something rather than the one item with the highest degree:

The hermitage is a most curious piece of architecture.

Comment: thanks PE Dant and Gustavson,
I understood your points but you didn't include all of them i guess. As is got to know one from my teacher.
-- If a determiner or possessive pronoun is used before it.
exa : You are his best friend.
: This tallest building in the world is going to remain at the top spot for quite some time.